# Rename keys on soft keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios5, soft-keyboard

I want to rename a few  buttons on the soft keyboard provided by the framework.
I have certain requirements which tell me to rename the   buttons on the keyboard for e.g. renaming the done button to next.
Can anyone please suggest how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at this documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

Specifically look at: returnKeyType

Answer (score 0):

The return key can also be be changed(into done,next etc which are the predefined values in an enum UIReturnKeuType)  through the xib file of a particular class under keyboard option.